# How to deploy this new 'React and Dotnet' Template, Which is Added in Visual Studio Version 17.8?

Tags: reactjs, .net, azure, docker, vite

I am trying to containerize this new 'React And Dotnet' template and want to deploy it as a single app on **Azure App Service**, like the previous one 'React With Dotnet' was available in Visual studio till version 17.7

**Example Of template**

[image: Example of Template]

**Docker File According to the docs** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022)

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Docker file to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

USER app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

USER app
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["barcodebtpl.client/nuget.config", "barcodebtpl.client/"]
COPY ["BarcodeBTPL.Server/BarcodeBTPL.Server.csproj", "BarcodeBTPL.Server/"]
COPY ["barcodebtpl.client/barcodebtpl.client.esproj", "barcodebtpl.client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./BarcodeBTPL.Server/./BarcodeBTPL.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BarcodeBTPL.Server"
RUN dotnet build "./BarcodeBTPL.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./BarcodeBTPL.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BarcodeBTPL.Server.dll"]
```

I know it is deployable as a single app [reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/new-react-typescript-spa-templates-and-more/) but unable to do so.

I have tried it to run in docker but it is only showing the swagger UI and when i am trying the base path directly e.g. `https://localhost:32776/` it is giving me 404 although it should render the weather forecast table as it in the the App.tsx.

**App.tsx**
[image: App.tsx]

**Update**
I have tried it to deploy on azure app service directly and it worked but not working with docker i don't know why so most probably there is an issue in my docker file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the steps in the [Debug section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022#debug)

The simplified version is to debug in a container in VS you need to:

1. Update your Docker launch profile to use the same ports as set in your https launch profiles's `applicationUrl` property, it should look like:

```json
"https": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7232;http://localhost:5079"
},
"Container (Dockerfile)": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
    "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080",
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": false,
  "useSSL": true,
  "httpPort": 5079,
  "sslPort": 7232
}
```

2. Configure VS to start the client and server project (Note you must ensure the correct launch profile is set first as it's difficult to set with multiple start-up projects)

   1. Right Click on your solution and select "Configure Startup Projects..."
      [image: Solution Context Menu -> Configure Startup Projects]
   2. Choose "Muliple startup projects", and configure your client and server are both set to Start:
      [image: Solution Property Pages]